# Setting connection strings in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am attempting to set my connection string for a MongoDB within the web.config
file.

I have the following :

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MongoConnect" value="mongodb://localhost" />
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Mongo" connectionString="mongodb://localhost"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I then try and access it using the WebConfigurationManager looking in both the ConnectionStrings and AppSettings collections, but neither have my values.

By the way I have this is both Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By the way I have this is both Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config

But it doesn't belong in either of those two locations - it belongs in web.config!

The `Web.*.config` files are [web.config transform](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx) files. They give instructions on how to *modify* the base web.config file for specific build configurations. In particular, Web.Debug.config modifies Web.config when you build in the Debug configuration.

If you don't have the connection strings in the base web.config, then there's nothing to modify!

See:

- [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Project Deployment Using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Deploying a Web Application Project Using a Web Deployment Package (Part 1 of 4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd483479.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

First of all don't care about the "Web.Debug.config" and "Web.Release.config" files.

Second: check the name of your server, maybe you need a login and password?

Third: just try using "(localhost)" and this: "mongodb://localhost" database="ASPNETDB"

Comment: The connection string works if I hard code it, its where I store it and how I access it I am struggling with.

Comment: "I am attempting to set my connection string for a MongoDB within the web.config file." Well... I was answering this.